# Node js bookshelf-modelBase, how to validate crypted passwords

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, bookshelf.js

I am using bookshelf-modelBase to model the user class.

I want salt the password before saving it to the DB but I also want to validate its length to be shorter than a given limit. So, in the model 'initialize' I have added a listener on the 'saving' event so to salt the password before saving. And I have also added a 'validate' block to check the password length with Joi.

The problem is that the validation listener added by bookshelf-modelBase is called AFTER my listener when the password is already salted and it is already longer than the limit. I have tried to unbind the validation listener but it does not work. It calls it all the same always after mine.

Below my current model definition.

```
var User = modelBase.extend({
  tableName: 'users',

  initialize: function() {
    this.removeListener('saving', this.validateSave);
    this.on('saving', this.validateAndProcessPassword);
  },

  validate: {
    username: Joi.string().min(6).max(15),
    password: Joi.string().max(15)
  },

  validateAndProcessPassword: function(model, attrs, options) {

    this.validateSave(model, attrs, options);

    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();

    var password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.get('password'), salt);

    this.set({password: password});
  }
});
```

The above code will call the validateSave twice. Once in my validateAndProcessPassword and once after it.

So, how can I perform the validation on the user input and still save a salted password?